# Flutter : Container on Container

Tags: flutter, containers

I try to make a container who is on another container in the border like that:[image]

I want do that without TextField. For the moment I have just [image]

To be more clear it's like a textfield without a textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Stack and Positioned for this custom.

Comment: Stack is exactly what I want ! Thx ^^